# Is it acceptable to put the bathroom entrance in the living room?

Tags: bathroom, layout

The bathroom (shower+toilet) and living room are located next to each other (see image bellow). One option for making an entrance to the bathroom is by putting the door on the living room’s wall (B), while another is by putting it on the other wall, which connects bathroom to the staircase (A).

Which option is more preferable, in your opinion, and how unacceptable is the other one?

[image]

Comment: Subjective.  There is no right/wrong answer.  Please refer to the [faq] http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: I have decided to ask in the first place because I didn’t know whether there was a right choice about it or not. Still, I understand your stance and will delete the question after several hours.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo There is an objectively wrong general answer: putting the bathroom off the kitchen.

Comment: @benrudgers, how's that wrong? I have seen several homes where a powder room is just off the kitchen, ostensibly for easily accessible vent stacks, aesthetics, whatever. If this is objectively wrong, I would suspect several builders are going to be in deep trouble either with code or the local inspectorate.

Comment: @alt "Built to code" means built to the lowest legal standard. The standard I am referencing is "Do not defecate where you eat." And yes, it's a higher standard than "Built to code".

Comment: @benrudgers, true. I agree with that sentiment, but as long as these are discrete rooms separated by walls and / or doors, and as long as each has its own separate air management system, you should be good to go. As far as providing audio accompaniment to diners in the kitchen or dining room, that's a separate topic :)

Comment: Put the door through to the stairs. Very few houses have the loo off the living room, and people will find it weird and unpleasant. To weigh in on the wrongness of kitchen loos - it's not compulsory to change this on old proprties in the UK, but you can't do it in a new build/planning application. There has to be an intermediate room, but it doesn't have to be big. The social point is that most folk don't want to see/hear/smell your loo from eating or relaxing space, so come directly off hall, stair or landing unless it's an ensuite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes (to the one question posed in your title).

To the question posed in your description: some people say that opinions are like a certain body part that everyone has (don't ask me for a citation; this is purely an observation). Hence, my opinion is just that - mine. And yours is yours.

There's a reason questions that are primarily opinion-based, or subjective, or cover a broad range of polarizing options, or aesthetic are off limits here.